# How to change flat file source using foreach loop container in an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

How can i change Flat file path using foreach loop container in SSIS

I'm having flat file which is under c:\sourcefile name of the file is "Flat(Date)"
for e.g Flat01aug2011.csv 
and every day it is generated by recent date so i need to picked up new file always and pass it to Flat File destination ,
so how can i traverse through folder and take new file which is having recent date.???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example in the below given link shows how you can loop through files of a given extension and load them into a database using Data Flow Task.

The example loads .csv files. The package uses a `Foreach loop container` to loop through the files and there is a `Data Flow task` within the loop container. The Data Flow task contains a Flat file source which changes based on the file being looped through. This is done by altering the Flat File Connection Manager path.

[**How do I move files to an archive folder after the files have been processed?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/ssis-2005-moving-file-after-parsing-in-foreach-loop-container/6703691#6703691)

Here is an example that loops through a list of directories within a given directory and picks the most recently created folder using Script Task and Foreach loop container. You need to make use of a similar logic to pick the most recently created file.

[**How do I pick the most recently created folder using Foreach loop container in SSIS package?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571881/ssis-for-each-pick-most-recent-folder/6684267#6684267)

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

Create two string data type variables namely `DirPath` and `FilePath`. Set the value C:\backup\ to the variable `DirPath`. Do not set any value to the variable `FilePath`.

[image: Variables]

Select the variable `FilePath` and select F4 to view the properties. Set the `EvaluateAsExpression` property to *True* and set the Expression property as `@[User::DirPath] + "Source" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252)  DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()) + "-" +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)`

[image: Expression]

Comment: Hi Siva thanks for link but i want to know that how can i get the latest file which is having name like FlatFile(TodayDate)

Comment: May i know How do format date “2011-08-11” using SSIS expression builder?
I.e. filename like "source 2011-08-11" I did like Created one variable which is having folder path : C\backup\

now inside expression builder how can i add date ??? i tried like @[User::DirPath]+"source"+ (DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))+"-"+(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH( DATEADD( "dd",-1, getdate() ))+"-"+(DT_STR,4,1252)DAY( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() )) +".CSV"

which is wrong please give me the expression which gives me output : "source 2011-08-11"

Answer (score 1):

In SSIS you can use 'ForEach Loop' container and set enumerator to file name.  For each loop container takes properties where you can provide folder location and file name format and extension.

With foreach loop container you can process multiple files too based on the file name.

See the tutorial at the following link.
http://www.sql-programmers.com/SQLResources/SQLServerIntegrationServiceSSIS/ForEachLoopContainer.aspx

Comment: Thanks But how can i get the latest file like FlatFile(TodayDate)

Comment: Then use expression for specifying your file name instead of pre-setting your file name as a foreach loop container property.