# How do I format date value as yyyy-mm-dd using SSIS expression builder?

Tags: ssis

hi I have taking flatfile source name dynamically I.e. filename like "source 2011-08-11"
I'm creating expression builder for taking most recent file as per filename.
I did like
Created one variable which is having folder path : C\backup\

now inside expression builder how can i add date ???
i tried like

```
@[User::DirPath]+"source"+ (DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))
+"-"+(DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH( DATEADD( "dd",-1, getdate() ))+"-"+(DT_STR,4,1252) 
DAY(DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() )) +".CSV"
```

which is wrong please give me the expression which gives me output :
 "source 2011-08-11"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Correct expression is

```
"source " + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() ) + "-" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) + "-" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +".CSV"
```

Comment: hey if i need to change date then where i need to change the value

Comment: +1, though I wish there was another way.  That degree of complexity for something almost every package needs is just obscene.  SSIS is worth every penny of its price.

Comment: That evals to 20110811 not 2011-08-11. You need a "-" + after the first 2 +.

Comment: Thanks. It was taking forever on how to do this - I thought there must be a simpler way but evidently not. 6 functions to format a date - pretty lame. FU MS.

Comment: Just remember - if it gets too ridiculous you can always use a script task with C#. However I would say the first rule of SSIS is "Try not to use a script task".

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you created a separate question. I was answering your other question [How to change flat file source using foreach loop container in an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913499/how-to-change-flat-file-source-using-foreach-loop-container-in-an-ssis-package) with the same answer. Anyway, here it is again.

Create two string data type variables namely `DirPath` and `FilePath`. Set the value C:\backup\ to the variable `DirPath`. Do not set any value to the variable `FilePath`.

[image: Variables]

Select the variable `FilePath` and select F4 to view the properties. Set the `EvaluateAsExpression` property to *True* and set the *Expression* property as `@[User::DirPath] + "Source" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252)  DATEPART("yy" , GETDATE()) + "-" +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)`

[image: Expression]

Answer (score 2):

```
"source " + LEFT((DT_WSTR, 50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)GETDATE(), 10) +".CSV"
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this was the most simple and useful for standard format