# How do I change the package variable value during runtime?

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm running an SSIS package and I want to set the value of a desired variable during runtime. Here an example

`variable1= 1145554478 nvarchar(30)`

I'm using nvarchar since I'm adding more characters to the string.

```
variable2= [ + variable1 + _S]
```

`variable1` and `variable2` are package variables.

I've searched for ways to set a value to the variables during runtime. As I thought, it seems that it could be done with an SQL Task Editor. So, I created one. Set the `variable1` as imput value, and `ResultSet` to single row, and set it to variable2.

then in the code I wrote

```
set Variable2 = '[' + ? + '_S]'
```

It's not working, here's the error

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the
>   query "set Variable2 = '[' + ? + '_S]'" failed with the following
>   error: "Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '='.". Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>   Task failed: Execute SQL Task.

Is a SQL Task editor the best way of setting a variable during runtime?

I think the code I wrote in the Task editor is wrong, since the code in there is not always the same ordinary SQL used regularly.

Comment: Yes Siva, you are not missing anything. Ive solve the issue from a Task Editor, but Id love to know your opinion too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set the value of the SSIS variable in your SQL statement, but rather RETURN the value and assign it to your variable.

Change your statement to

```
SELECT '[' + ? + '_S]'
```

Change your result set to "Single Row" and then under "Result Set" on the left add your variable with the Result Name of 0

Comment: Nice one msmucker, thanks a lot, it worked. Didn't know about the '0' in the ResultSet

Comment: It's the index of the column for the single row result set, so if you were to select something else (SELECT '[' + ? + '_S]', 'SomethingElse') you would use the Result Name of 1

Comment: And so on, I get it now. Thanks a lot! this will be usefull in future processes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to manipulate the value of a variable during runtime based on another variable's value. The sample uses SSIS 2008 R2 but the functionality has been the same on all SSIS versions.

- Create a new SSIS package.
- Right-click anywhere on the package and select `Variables` from the context menu. *Variables* pane will be displayed.
- On the *Variables* pane, create two new variables named `Variable1` and `Variable2` of data type **`String`**.
- Let's set the `Variable1` with the value **Test_Value**.

  [image: Variables]
- Select the second variable Variable2 and press F4 to bring the Properties pane.
- On the properties pane, change the property `EvaluateAsExpression` to **True**.
- Then click on the *Ellipsis* button on the `Expression` property.

  [image: Properties of Variable2]
- On the Expression Builder dialog, paste the expression **`"[" +  @[User::Variable1] + "_S]"`** in the `Expression` text area.
- If you click on the Evaluate Expression button, you will see the value that the Variable2 would evaluate to. During runtime, the variable `Variable2` will automatically evaluate to the value present in `Variable1` using the expression.
- Expression Builder can allow to formulate more complex expressions as well. [Click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6925391/756519) to see another expression example.

Hope that helps.

[image: Expression Builder]

Comment: Thanks so much Siva. Your explanation was not just correct but so very well explained. Thanks again, a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would (typically) be to create a script task and just write the code in C# or VB.

Comment: Im not versed enough in C# to create even a simple code like that. that's why im trying to do it from SQL. Will google some C# though

Comment: @Daniel - google should help you here.  The code you'd need to write should only be one line or so.