# SSIS Web Service Task - Input variable

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

Im trying to download some data from web services using **Web Service Task** component in **SSIS**. Everything works fine when I insert required **Input value** manually. The required input value have to be in dateTime type but it only works when I munually write datetime in **YYYY-MM-DD** or **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM** format.

[image]

But that of course is not what I wanted to do.
So I created a variable with **DateTime** data type with simple expression:

```
(DT_DATE) GETDATE()
```

But that gives me format **DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM** instead of **YYYY-MM-DD** or **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM**.
When I execute the package it goes into error message:

*[Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method. The error is: Method 'ProxyNamespace.Service.Method' not found..
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".*

I think its only because my variable is in incorrect format. Any suggestions how to change it to desired dateTime format while data type of variable remains with DateTime option ? Thanks !

****EDIT :****
So I managed to solve the problem with the **DateTime** format, I simply changed the date format on my server to **YYYY-MM-DD** in the Windows environment (Control Panel - Region - Formats) and it also changed in **SSIS**.

But the problem still persists, when I check the box in the input section that I use a **Variable** and select my variable in the correct format as a DateTime with the correct value YYYY-MM-DD, I still get an error message and nothing happens.

Do you have any other solutions to my problem?

Comment: have a look at this, should get you moving in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922517/how-do-i-format-date-value-as-yyyy-mm-dd-using-ssis-expression-builder

Comment: @TimMylott thanks Tim, you were right, that article helped me solve the format problem, but the error message problem still persists after I use variable in correct format and value :(